# CSS positioning boxes inside containers

Tags: html, css

How would I make my content-container have the same padding on the right as the sidebar and also located a few pixels next to sidebar with its top the same level as sidebar?

http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/Pvr73/2/

This is confusing for me as I don't know all the properties that I can use.

My html:

{%  load staticfiles %}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="home-button">
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/Pvr73/6/ What do you mean about `padding` are you talking about `margin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use float:left and float:right to align them in same level.

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #CCFF99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:left;
}


.content-container {
    background-color: #E6D1E6;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:right;
}
```

Check this jsFiddle for the changed code

http://jsfiddle.net/Pvr73/5/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check the fiddle, and ignore the colors just change it for better visibility. ;)

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvr73/7/)

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

.home-button {
background-color: #FFCCFF;
height: 45px;
width: 175px;
}


.sidebar {
background-color: green;
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
margin-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}

.container {
width: 70%;
background-color: #E0E0E0;
height: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
padding-left: 4%;
padding-right: 4%;
padding-top: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%

}

.content-container {
background-color: red;
position: relative;
width: 320px;
height: 80%;
padding-right: 4%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvr73/8/)

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float:left;/* added */
}
.content-container {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    float:right;/* added */
    margin:20px 5px;/* added */
}
```